# pyplot legend scaling inconsistent

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I am plotting several bar charts with pyplot.bar() in a for loop. The only thing that changes from one iteration to the next is the data set, so the bar limits and hights - albeit only slightly. Also, I plot an axvline, which is the only thing that is labeled for the legend.
However, the legend box I plot with

```
plt.axvline(comp_limit, color='gray', linestyle='--', label='completeness limit')
plt.legend(numpoints=1, loc='upper left')
```

changes its and its font's size from plot to plot, which I don't get - since the position and the content of the legend always stays the same. What is the legend size a function of and why does it change?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you put together a more complete (but minimal!) example which demonstrates this problem?  From what is here I can't make heads or tails of the problem.

Comment: See http://sscce.org/